# How to check user has access to file or not(using service ID)

Tags: java, file

I'm connecting to a server and getting files from there and scanning it using java code.
Before scanning the files , I wanted to check whether the files has access to the given Service ID?

Comment: Could you provide us with more on how you are contacting the server? Some code could be helpful.

Comment: Can you expand on _check whether the files has access to the given Service ID_ What _Service ID_ are you referring to? Is it a Web service? How does a file have access to a service?

Comment: lets suppose we have files in some server and we login to server using LoginId/userId and password. if there is a one file it is accessible only to me others cant access it bcz their Login/userId dont have permission.how to check this permission in java

Comment: So you are asking how to check whether a certain user has permission to read a file on a remote server, correct?

Comment: yes, exactly the same I want